# begin the read of json file at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi everyone I try to get a json file with ajax to add some div in my html.

But i Want to take in first the last data on the json file.

My code :

```
 jQuery(function(){

 $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/getsomejson',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                           {
                            ...
                           }
                     }
        });
       });
```

I try that but not attempt effect : `for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++){`

How can I do that ?

Comment: `for( var i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for`-Loops can begin and end almost everywhere you want them to. You've used a loop that starts at 0 and ends at `data.length-1`. What you want is one that begins at `data.length-1` and ends at 0:

```
success: function (data) {
  for (let i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    //your code
  }
}
```

You want to start at `data.length-1`, because the array is 0-indexed. The length of an array is thus always one more than the last item's index.